# Cannot get cookies from WebView page

Tags: android, kotlin, cookies, webview

My goal is to open the Instagram login page, go through authorization and get the cookies I need (for example `session_id`).

Before all I declare this view and cookieManager:

```
webView = view.findViewById(R.id.web_view)

cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()
cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true)
```

Then clear all cookies that may be cached before:

```
private fun clearCookies() {
    webView.clearCache(true)
    webView.clearFormData()
    webView.clearHistory()
    webView.clearSslPreferences()
    webView.clearMatches()
    WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData()
}
```

The webview loading code:

```
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
        view.loadUrl(url)
        return false
    }

    override fun onLoadResource(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url)
        val cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(url)
        
        //this log returns "null"
        Log.d("postNotification", cookies)
        
        // do some things with cookies...
    }
}

webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

//set my custom webUserAgent
webView.settings.userAgentString = InstagramClient.Configuration.current.webUserAgent

webView.post {
    run {
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
    }
}
```

```
var webUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 5 Build/LMY48B; wv) " +
    "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

After login, nothing happens, and the cookie check log displays null. And Instagram itself didn’t seem to notice the login and just refreshes the page without going to the account.

I recorded a video of this behavior:
[image]

I will be grateful for any help!